# Swift and SpriteKit: Move two sprites as one cohesive unit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to move two sprites in Swift as one cohesive unit? Assume we have two rectangles. How can we ensure both rectangles move together in unison, almost as if they formed one sprite?

Right now, we're using `moveTo` on both sprites inside the same `runBlock`, giving both actions the same properties (e.g., timing mode, duration). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add both nodes as children of a `SKNode` instance, and then just move the parent node:

```
let rectNode1 = SKShapeNode(rect: aRect)
let rectNode2 = SKShapeNode(rect: aRect)

let parentNode = SKNode()
parentNode.addChild(rectNode1)
parentNode.addChild(rectNode2)
// configure positions etc...

parentNode.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 25.0), duration: 1.0))
```

Comment: What about rotation? I tried a rotation `SKAction` on the parent node and failed miserably :(